# iOS reverse engineering After modifying the __RESTRICT crash

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, tweak

Log:

```
Apr 25 09:33:53 iPhone SpringBoard[310] <Notice>: MIS: Could not copy code directory hash.
Apr 25 09:33:53 iPhone SpringBoard[310] <Notice>: MIS: Could not copy code directory hash (error 0xe8008001).
Apr 25 09:33:53 iPhone SpringBoard[310] <Notice>: MIS: Could not extract cdhash
Apr 25 09:33:53 iPhone SpringBoard[310] <Notice>: MIS: Could not copy code directory hash.
Apr 25 09:33:53 iPhone SpringBoard[310] <Notice>: MIS: Could not copy code directory hash (error 0xe8008001).
Apr 25 09:33:53 iPhone SpringBoard[310] <Notice>: MIS: Could not extract cdhash
Apr 25 09:33:53 iPhone com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (UIKitApplication:com.qiyi.iphone[0x1126][1324]) <Notice>: Service exited due to signal: Killed: 9
Apr 25 09:33:53 iPhone assertiond[336] <Warning>: Unable to obtain a task name port right for pid 1324: (os/kern) failure (5)
Apr 25 09:33:53 iPhone SpringBoard[310] <Warning>: Unable to register for exec notifications: No such process
Apr 25 09:33:53 iPhone SpringBoard[310] <Warning>: Unable to obtain a task name port right for pid 1324: (os/kern) failure (5)
Apr 25 09:33:53 iPhone SpringBoard[310] <Warning>: Unable to obtain a task name port right for <FBApplicationProcess: 0x160abf690; com.qiyi.iphone; pid: 1324>
Apr 25 09:33:53 iPhone SpringBoard[310] <Warning>: Application'UIKitApplication:com.test.Demo[0x1126]' exited abnormally via signal.
Apr 25 09:33:53 iPhone SpringBoard[310] <Warning>: Application '(null)' exited for an unknown reason.
```